# Trait to detect non-inherited typedef

Tags: c++, typedef, type-traits

Is there a way to detect, if `struct` has `typedef` which is not inherited?

Following code fails on `C`

```
#include <iostream>

struct A { };
struct B : public A { typedef A Base; };
struct C : public B {};

template<typename T>
struct to_void
{
    typedef void type;
};

template <typename T, typename dummy = void>
struct has_base_typedef : std::false_type {};

template <typename T>
struct has_base_typedef<T, typename to_void<typename T::Base>::type> : std::true_type {};

int main()
{
    std::cout << has_base_typedef<A>::value;
    std::cout << has_base_typedef<B>::value;
    std::cout << has_base_typedef<C>::value;
}
```

trait for `C` gives `true` since `Base` is inherited (`private` modifier doesn't help AFAIK)

My goal is to get the snippet to print `010`

[Small example](http://ideone.com/93sYxU) to play with on ideone.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you want to block implicit propagation of the `Base` alias to the derived class, which I don't think is possible. The only way I can think of to achieve something close to what you want is the following:

```
struct C;

struct A {};
struct B : public A {
  using Base = A; 
  using Derived = C;
};
struct C : public B { };

template<typename T>
struct to_void {
    typedef void type;
};

template <typename T, typename dummy = void>
struct has_base_typedef : std::false_type {};

template <typename T>
struct has_base_typedef<T, std::enable_if_t<!std::is_same<typename T::Derived, T>::value, 
                            typename to_void<typename T::Base>::type>> : std::true_type {};
```

[**Live Demo**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/398de66f1fd8c2eb)

Comment: OP expected `010` and it got  [101010](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2352671/101010) :-)

Comment: thank you for the answer, unfortunately this is not the general approach I'm looknig for. Derived classes could be more than one (typelist have to be used) and struct could be within a library and should not (cannot) be modified when new derived class is created...